# How do you put 3 arrays in memory and then reference them to avoid hitting API calls more then 3 times

Tags: php, arrays, performance, optimization

In my code I have 3 functions basically nested. One calls one which then calls another. Code execution is very slow. I am led to believe because these API calls can contain a lot of data and that they are getting ran more then once it is having an impact on performance.

Code sample as follows:

```
$data['object'] = 'domain';
    $data['action'] = 'read';
    $data['format'] = 'json'; 
        if($response = $this->request($data)){
            $obj = json_decode($response,true);
        .......
                }
        }else{
            return $response;
        }
```

So basically, obj gets all the data.

Can I just create say a private array in some form and then write all my results to it and then run my statements against it instead of calling the API several times?

Comment: So where are you calling the api multiple times?

Comment: This may be better suited on Stack Overflow

Comment: @TimmyJim: You are right. I posted on the wrong site by mistake. Opps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am led to believe because these API calls can contain a lot of data and that they are getting ran more then once it is having an impact on performance.

The golden rule of optimization is that you **do not optimize without measuring first**.  Use a profiler to run your code and tell you what code is getting executed the most and is taking the longest time.  If you don't measure, you could be speeding up the wrong thing.

In your case, with PHP, you'll probably want to start with [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/).

Once you know what is being slow, then you can concern yourself with how to speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't expect the returned data to change from one call to the next then, yes, you can store the results locally (and even pre-process them for easier use) and then re-use them from there. In the fancy technical jargon (and depending on the implementation) this would be called "caching" or "[memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)".